# Change background color of jpanel using RGB values

Tags: java

I want to change background color of a jpanel using RGB values, 
I have found a way to get HSB color values,

```
stdinfoPanel.setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(154, 254, 25));
```

Can any one give a proper way to get color from RGB values instead of HSB values like in the above mentioned code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Just use some of the constructors.. [color javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(int,%20int,%20int))

```
Color color = new Color(0,255,0); //for example
```

Panel also must be opaque in order to see the color changed.

Answer (score 2):

The line you're looking for is: `panel.setBackground(new Color(0,0,255));`

The numbers in the `Color` constructor represent Red, Green, and Blue values respectively.

Comment: Thank you for the correct answer.  For your info, Google brought me here.  I would have voted this answer up if the tone had been kept more neutral vs the usual SO style.

Comment: I wrote this answer so long ago that I was still going through my passive aggressive phase. Will Edit.